# How can I use Capybara to check that the correct items are listed?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm trying to use Capybara to test that a list contains the correct items. For example:

```
<table id="rodents">
  <tr><td class="rodent_id">1</td><td class="rodent_name">Hamster</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="rodent_id">2</td><td class="rodent_name">Gerbil</td></tr>
</table>
```

This list **should** contain ids 1 and 2, but **should not** include 3.

What I'd like is something like:

```
ids = ? # get the contents of each row's first cell
ids.should include(1)
ids.should include(2)
ids.should_not include(3)
```

**How might I do something like that?**

I'm answering with a couple of unsatisfactory solutions I've found, but I'd love to see a better one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a slightly simplified expression:

```
  rodent_ids = page.all('table#rodents td.rodent_id').map(&:text)
```

From there, you can do your comparisons.

```
  rodent_ids.should include(1)
  rodent_ids.should include(2)
  rodent_ids.should_not include(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Looking for specific rows and ids

A bad solution:

```
within ('table#rodents tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)') do
  page.should have_content @rodent1.id
end

within ('table#rodents tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)') do
  page.should have_content @rodent1.id
end

page.should_not have_selector('table#rodents tr:nth-child(3)')
```

This is verbose and ugly, and doesn't really say that id 3 shouldn't be in the table.

Answer (score 2):

### Gathering the ids into an array

This is what I was looking for:

```
  rodent_ids = page.all('table#rodents td:nth-child(1)').map{|td| td.text}
```

From there, I can do:

```
  rodent_ids.should include(1)
  rodent_ids.should include(2)
  rodent_ids.should_not include(3)
```

Or just:

```
  rodent_ids.should eq(%w[1 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `has_table?`

A bad solution:

```
  page.has_table?('rodents', :rows => [
                    ['1', 'Hamster'],
                    ['2', 'Gerbil']   
                  ]
                 ).should be_true
```

This is very clear to read, but:

- It's brittle. If the table structure or text changes at all, it fails.
- If it fails, it just says it expected false to be true; I don't know an easy way to compare what the table really looks like with what's expected, other than `print page.html`
- The `has_table?` method [might get removed at some point](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ruby-capybara/1pHXUbT3AL8/b0YOih4xP3MJ)